# How do I loop through a raw_input multiple times?

Tags: python, list, raw-input

For my customer quoting system, I have written a couple blocks of code with raw_input, if, elif, else statements and mathematical equations to work out the price of carpeting a room.
Now, I want to include a 50 percent discount if the customer writes into the raw_input 3 rooms, and that 50 percent discount is discounted to the cheapest room out of the three. Now if they want 4 rooms done, they get the cheapest room done free.

My dilemma's however are, What is the code to loop through the questions "What is the length" and "What is the width" the same amount of times they put for the question "How many rooms are there". So basically I want the code to ask the length and width questions for the number of rooms they put.
And lastly, when it comes to discounting them, how do I get (out of the rooms they put with the measurements included) the lowest priced room and half that price. As in, where would the code store it for me to be able to retrieve it and discount it.

Thanks if you've stayed this long. My Code so far, Below.

```
NumberOfRooms = int(raw_input("How many rooms are you looking to carpet? "))

LengthOfRoom = int(raw_input("What is the length of the room in Meters? "))

WidthOfRoom = int(raw_input("What is the width of the room in Meters? "))

areaOfRoom = LengthOfRoom * WidthOfRoom

CarpetType = raw_input("What type of carpet do you want? (Standard, Premium,            Executive) ")

print "The area of your room is " + str(areaOfRoom)
print "LengthOfRoom = %s, WidthOfRoom = %s, CarpetType = %s." %     (LengthOfRoom, WidthOfRoom, CarpetType)

Standard = 20
Premium = 30
Executive = 50

StandardRoomPrice = (areaOfRoom / 3.66) * Standard * NumberOfRooms
PremiumRoomPrice = (areaOfRoom / 3.66) * Premium * NumberOfRooms
ExecutiveRoomPrice = (areaOfRoom / 3.66) * Executive * NumberOfRooms
VolumeDiscount = 0.5

CarpetTyping = CarpetType

if CarpetTyping == "Standard":
    print StandardRoomPrice
elif CarpetTyping == "Premium":
    print PremiumRoomPrice
else:
print ExecutiveRoomPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop in range `num_rooms` taking width and height together:

```
from operator import mul

from itertools import count


prem_rate = 3.66
disc_rate = 1.83

while True:
    try:
       num_rooms = int(raw_input("How many rooms are you looking to carpet? "))
       break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number")

# use for dict keys for each room
cn = count(1)
room_measurements = {}

# validate and confirm input making sure we get a valid measurement for each room
while len(room_measurements) != num_rooms:
    print(room_measurements)
    try:
        m = map(int, raw_input("Enter length and width of room separated by a space i.e 12 10? ").split())
        # user entered something like 1010
        if len(m) != 2:
            print("Input must be in format width height")
            continue
        # make sure user is happy with sizes the entered
        confirm = raw_input("You entered width {} and height {}\n Press y to confirm or any key to try again".format(*m))
        if confirm.lower() != "y":
            continue
        room_measurements["room {}".format(next(cn))] = m
    # catch when user enters input that cannot be cast to int
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")

# set disc_room to False initially
disc_room = False
if len(room_measurements) > 2:
    mn_size = min(room_measurements, key=lambda x: mul(*room_measurements[x]))
    disc_room = room_measurements[mn_size] 
    # remove room so we can calculate separately later
    del room_measurements[mn_size]

# if we get three or more rooms if disc_room will evaluate to True
# so calculate prem rate for larger rooms and add discounted room cost
if disc_room:
    total = sum(mul(*x) * prem_rate for x in room_measurements.itervalues()) + (mul(*disc_room) * disc_rate)
    print(total)
else:
    # else less than 3 rooms so just calculate prem rate
    total = sum(mul(*x) * prem_rate for x in room_measurements.itervalues())
```

Dealing with money you might want to look into the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to store the user inputs, so that you know what the customer has ordered in total. I rewrote your code a little (neither perfect nor complete but it should get you started). Finding the lowest prized room is just a matter of iterating over the orders and calculating the individual price, but I'll leave this up to you as an exercise.

```
orders = {}

num_rooms = int(raw_input("How many rooms are you looking to carpet? "))

for i in range(1, num_rooms + 1):
    order = {}
    print 'Room', i
    order['length'] = int(raw_input("What is the length of the room in Meters? "))
    order['width'] = int(raw_input("What is the width of the room in Meters? "))
    order['area'] = order['width'] * order['length']
    order['carpet_type'] = raw_input("What type of carpet do you want? ([S]tandard, [P]remium, [E]xecutive) ")
    orders[i] = order

ROOM_FACTORS = { 'S' : 20,
                'P' : 30,
                'E' : 50 }

total_price = 0.0
for order_id in orders:
    order = orders[order_id]
    total_price += order['area'] / 3.66 * ROOM_FACTORS[order['carpet_type']]

# Discount
if len(orders) > 2:
    total_price *= 0.5

print 'Total price is:', total_price
```

Output:

```
How many rooms are you looking to carpet? 2
Room 1
What is the length of the room in Meters? 1
What is the width of the room in Meters? 1
What type of carpet do you want? ([S]tandard, [P]remium, [E]xecutive) S
Room 2
What is the length of the room in Meters? 2
What is the width of the room in Meters? 2
What type of carpet do you want? ([S]tandard, [P]remium, [E]xecutive) P
Total price is: 38.2513661202
```